# Error with django-registration module: AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")

Tags: django, django-models

I am having a problem getting the Django registration module to work. I am relatively new to Django, having only worked through a few examples, now wanting to rebuild a site using user registration, that I've previously made with python.

I am using Python 2.7, Django 1.7.1, and my operating system is Ubuntu 14.04. I'm also using Eclipse/PyDev for my IDE.

I keep getting the error message: 
   raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.

I have installed both the django-registration and django-registration-redux modules, understanding that there may issues with installing django-registration in Django 1.7. Should I copy the registration module directly into my app, although not advised, but for troubleshooting? Should I uninstall something before I install a new package?

The django-registration module resides in "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages." I'm not sure where the django-registration-redux module should have ended up at, although it deposited "django_registration_redux-1.1.egg-info" with the dist-packages.

I have added 'registration', to the settings file, and to my urls' file pattern I've added: (r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),

I've read numerous on-line postings about this issue, but I can't get around this block. Should I uninstall Django 1.7.1, and install Django 1.6 to avoid this impasse?

Thanks,
Walter Goedecke

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using django-allauth instead of django-registration?
As I understand it, django-registration is no longer being maintained.

Answer (score 0):

Were you able to resolve this?

When you say “I have installed both the django-registration and django-registration-redux modules”, do you mean you are trying to use both at the same time, or you tried one and then the other? You should only be using django-registration-redux, I believe django-registration stopped being maintained during one of the Django 1.6 releases, maybe it was 1.5 don’t recall. If its of any help, we have Django 1.7.9, Django 1.8.1, and Django 1.8.3 working with django-registration-redux 1.1.

It sounds like you are installing your python packages system wide (you said its residing in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages). There is a great tool called virtualenv that lets you keep all of your projects isolated, in their own virtual environment with their unique dependences. This way one project can be using django 1.5 while another is using django 1.7, one project can use django-registration-redux while the other uses allauth, etc. The other great thing about it, is that it makes your projects more portable, easier to share, and easier to update.

If you haven’t tried it yet, you should check it out!
http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

I found this link very helpful when I was first getting started with Python and Django development:
http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/12/18/starting-a-django-16-project-the-right-way/